# Failed at the adf-cli-acs-aps-template@3.5.0 start script

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, yeoman, alfresco-share

What is causing this error - Failed at the adf-cli-acs-aps-template@3.5.0 start script? 
I was able to install fine with command - `npm install`

My environment..

```
PS C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web> node -v
v10.15.3

PS C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web> yo --version
2.0.6

Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.0.3
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, material, material-moment-adapter, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.803.19
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.803.19
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.803.19
@angular-devkit/core               7.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.3.9
@angular/cli                       7.3.9
@angular/flex-layout               7.0.0-beta.24
@ngtools/webpack                   8.3.19
@schematics/angular                7.3.9
@schematics/update                 0.13.9
rxjs                               6.5.3
typescript                         3.1.6
webpack                            4.39.2

install the latest version of the generator-alfresco-adf-app:

    npm install -g generator-alfresco-adf-app@latest

    yo alfresco-adf-app
```

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web> npm start

> adf-cli-acs-aps-template@3.5.0 start C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web
> npm run validate-config && ng serve --open


> adf-cli-acs-aps-template@3.5.0 validate-config C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web
> ajv validate -s node_modules/@alfresco/adf-core/app.config.schema.json -d ./src/app.config.json --errors=text --verbose

./src/app.config.json valid
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
    at MergeMapSubscriber._registry.compile.pipe.operators_1.concatMap.validatorResult [as project] (C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:215:42)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:69:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:55:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:86:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:17:28
    at Object.subscribeToResult (C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:65:54)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:55:14)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! adf-cli-acs-aps-template@3.5.0 start: `npm run validate-config && ng serve --open`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the adf-cli-acs-aps-template@3.5.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\drbanner\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-20T15_29_48_585Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\drbanner\dev\myproject\web>
```